# How does using a different reference yield the right result? Javascript, Beginner, Arrays and Functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```js
const todos = [{
    text: 'Eat breakfast',
    completed: true
  }, {
    text: 'Eat Lunch',
    completed: true
  },
  {
    text: 'Eat Dinner',
    completed: false
  }
]

const removeTodo = function(todos, todoText) {
  const index = todos.findIndex(function(todo) {
    return todo.text.toLowerCase() === todoText.toLowerCase()
  })

  if (index > -1) {
    todos.splice(index, 1)
  }
}

removeTodo(todos, 'Eat breakfast')
console.log(todos)
```

**Question:**

1. How does return `todo.text` refer to the `todos` array? should not the array name be exact i.e. with an `s` when working with it?
2. What is the point of defining the `todo` function argument? If it is an arbitrary name then how does it refer to the specific `todos` array in the function? i.e. how does the program refer to the array since `todo` is an argument whereas `todos` is
   the array?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. `findIndex` will loop through all the items in the array `todos` and then assign that to a locally scoped parameter called todo.    2. So you can use `removeTodo` on another array that has the same shape..

Comment: It seems like you don't understand how `findIndex` and callback functions work.

Comment: 1. but when is todo.text defined?

Comment: `.text` is defined in your array, and `todo` is a reference to one of your array items.  IOW todo will equal  `todos[0] , todos[1], todos[2]`,  so `todo.text` is the same as `todos[0].text, todos[1].text, todos[2].text` as is loops through the array.

Comment: Okay so i believe i get it now. Each time the call back function loops with each item, it assigns the items to todo which is arbitrarily named.  The function defined within then sees if the argument matches with the item content. If so, it removes said item. Please correct or add on if i am not right. Thanks so much Keith and Barmar.

Comment: Nearly, the remove bit is the `splice` that happens after your findIndex..  the callback in the findIndex is just finding the index to remove..

Comment: and why is it removed if it is >-1 ?

Comment: Yes, you've got it..  -1 is what is returned if nothing is found during `findIndex`..